# How to configure Xcode to place build products inside project folder?

Tags: xcode, macos

In Xcode (6.3), you can change the default build location in Preferences ▸ Locations ▸ Derived Data ▸ Advanced.

I've now set it to "Custom" and "Relative to Workspace" so it would always be located relatively to the location of the project folder, and specified the build folder as `Build`.

However, the `Build` folder appears in the *same* directory as the .xcodeproj folder. How can I make it go **inside** it instead?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You want your Build folder to go inside your .xcodeproj itself?

Comment: @Siriss Preferably yes.

Comment: I strongly recommend *against* doing that.  Xcode expects only certain types of files to be in certain places within an "`.xcodeproj`" folder.  You may get unexpected results in a current or future version of the Xcode IDE.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Oh okay, good to know. That would probably be a good answer also.